# How can I parse external link url using native angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, url

everyone. Sometimes I need some way to get some part of external site url in my angular code. But there's obviously no way to do it with native angular services, and I don't wanna use some Jquery library for parsing url. I need some service for url parsing which. Where can I find such service? Thx!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it in [Vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/).

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Comment: Can I get any GET parameter by this way?

Comment: Of course you can. In my example you'd parse `parse.search`. Also see: [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Comment: OMG! Do you really have to create a virtual `<a>` element to parse a link?

Comment: You could also reuse an existing one, assuming the `href` attribute contains the same URL you want to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the [$sce service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce):

```
function($scope, $sce) {
 $scope.getHtml = function() {
   return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(myUrlHere);
 };
}
```

As mentioned in other post, provided that this is not subject to CORS.

Answer (score -4):

By Parsing, I'm assuming you mean fetching of content/data from a url.

Proving the url allows any domain ( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' ) or your domain, **Angular does have ajax functions built in**, simular to jquery et all.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Copied direct from the anguar doc

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: No, actually, by parsing I meant getting some parts of url string for example get parameters.

Comment: oh ok : ) regular js will do then, Angular would not have any need to recreate that. - use of externalurlstring.split("/") and such - I thought Simone's answer is pretty cool