# How do I test my HTTP call when I use a config to build the URL?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, httpbackend, angular-mock

In my project I build some of my HTTP requests like so:

```
var options = {
    params:{
        foo: 'bar'
        hello: world
    }
};
$http.get("my/service", options)
```

Which means that the final HTTP call looks something like `my/service?foo=bar&hello=worldVar`

How do I setup my `$httpBackend` to account for this?

The problems I see are:

1. I'm not guaranteed order in my parameters with this style, which means setting up the first parameter in `expectGet` will be hard.
2. Its hard to test calls when I really don't care about the parameters

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found to this is to use the override of `expect`/`when` that accepts a function, and to mix it in with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21516924/1305516) answer. That gets me to something like

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(function(url){
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href=url;
    return parser.search.indexOf('foo=bar') > -1 && 
           parser.search.indexOf('hello=world') > -1;
})
```

or if I don't care about the parameters I can just test for `parser.pathname`.

However, this still isnt perfect because its a pain to test that I dont have extra parameters, so Im still actively looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about the parameters, you can just use regex to match to the static part of the URL:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/my\/service/)
```